GAS with AT&T syntax - creating a label by concatenating a variable of a macro
I have an assembly code that generates ISR (interrupt service routine) stubs. I want to automate this process, and for each of the interrupts (there are 256) generate it's own unique stub. This is where I use assembly macro in the following fashion:
first, I have a dependancy file that looks like this:
# File name - isrs_gen.cpp
ISR_NOERRORCODE 0
ISR_NOERRORCODE 1
ISR_NOERRORCODE 2
ISR_NOERRORCODE 3
ISR_NOERRORCODE 4
ISR_NOERRORCODE 5
ISR_NOERRORCODE 6
ISR_NOERRORCODE 7
ISR_ERRORCODE 8

This is part of the dependancy file and as you can see the file contains some constants that are called from a different file. The other file looks like this:
# File name - isr_asm.s
.macro ISR_NOERRORCODE num
    .global ISR\num
ISR\num:
    pushl $0              # push dummy error code
    pushl $num            # push interrupt number
    jmp isr_common
.endm

.macro ISR_ERRORCODE num
    .global ISR\num
ISR\num:
                        # cpu pushes an error code to the stack
    pushl $num           # push interrupt number
    jmp isr_common
.endm

.include "idt/isrs_gen.inc"

As you can see I use the .include instruction after defining the macros in order to invoke them and create 256 stubs. When I try to link the code (I also have other code files) I get the following error:
ld: isr_asm.o: in function `ISR0':
(.text+0x3): undefined reference to `num'
ld: isr_asm.o: in function `ISR1':
(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `num'
ld: isr_asm.o: in function `ISR2':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `num'
ld: isr_asm.o: in function `ISR3':
(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `num'
ld: isr_asm.o: in function `ISR4':
(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `num'
ld: isr_asm.o:(.text+0x3f): more undefined references to `num' follow

Any idea?
Thanks!

You probably meant to use push $\num instead of push $num

@MichaelPetch Thanks, and how do I fix the label?

Not sure what you mean as the labels are correct. The error is in the push

@MichaelPetch Yeah, I figured that a while ago, thanks for your help!
